# Is there an efficient way to fontify matches of thousands of different strings in a buffer?

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I have a list of thousands of different strings made up of different numbers of words (e.g. names of specific people) that I would like to fontify in a buffer. Some applications I could use for something like this are highlighting names from a contact list, highlighting chemical names in a notebook, etc.

I know that technically one fontifies a pattern, but in this case the pattern is a literal string (from the long list) to match, so I call this fontifying a string.

For small lists of strings, I can do something like this:

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
 `((,(string-join (cl-loop for name in list-of-names
              collect
              (format "\\(%s\\)" name))
         "\\|") . font-lock-keyword-face)))
```

And this works fine. But this doesn't scale well for much larger lists of patterns. I get an error of `Invalid regexp: "Regular expression too big"` if I try to put several thousand patterns joined by OR's.

Is there another strategy to do something like this with fontification?

A partial solution that seems to work reasonably well for strings with two words separated by a space in them is that I use a search function in the font-lock rule. In the function I break the region from point to limit into bigrams, and then I check if each bigram (joined by a space) is in a hashtable of the strings to match, and if it is, I set some match data. This works for strings made of two words separated by a space, but doesn't work if there is more than one space (I could probably live with standardizing this though). The same approach works for single words, I just use a separate function for that. I could probably extend it to 3-grams for matches with 3 words. I am interested in other solutions if anyone can think of them.

Comment: Is your concern about the performance of a complex regexp of alternation (OR's)? Or is it about the performance of matching thousands of different regexps? I tried to interpret your "strings" in the original title and question body as the pattern to be matched, but for the title it wasn't clear to me. Font-lock doesn't fontify strings; it fontifies pattern matches (stretches of buffer text). Feel free to correct my attempt at clarification if it made things worse.

Comment: I have mixed feelings on the clarification. The strings are patterns to match, but I want exact matches only in this question. I think the clarification (while technically correct) doesn't make it better for the specific question, although it is a more general.

Comment: I get an error of `Invalid regexp: "Regular expression too big"` if I try to put several thousand patterns joined by OR's.

Comment: As I said, feel free to edit/correct the edit. Thx.

Comment: Please consider adding the info about that error msg to the question. It seems to clarify the motivation.

Comment: I have updated the question with some details that might help explain some of the nuances.

Answer (score 1):

> I get an error of Invalid regexp: "Regular expression too big" if I try to put several thousand patterns joined by OR's.

`regexp-opt` exists for creating efficient regexps from a set of strings.

I've no idea whether that's actually going to cope with your input, mind; but if it manages to do so then you'll get a *far* more efficient pattern out of it.

---

The ways in which first and last names will be mixed and matched is still going to bloat things though (and probably a lot), so other food for thought on that...

You could divide the matching into first-name and remainder.  Have a pattern for only the possible first names, and for each first name have a pattern for the possible full names beginning with that specific first name.  When you get a match for a word which is someone's first name, pull up the other associated regexp and check whether you're looking at one of those.

Each of those regexps would be *relatively* concise, I think -- although you'll have plenty of duplication between each of the secondary regexps.

You could also have just two regexps, and search for "all possible first names" followed by "all possible remainders", and if you get a match for *that* you can check to see whether the matched text is *actually* one of your known names.

Comment: regexp-opt also leads to `Invalid regexp: "Regular expression too big"` in my case. I haven't had any luck defining regexps this way, and use the "inverse" lookup approach  described above because it does scale. A sequential lookup is a good idea though, I will give that some thought. Thanks.